# Do your +1's affect your own Google results?

Tags: google-search, google-plus

Your Google plus connections' +1s affect your own Google results. But how about your +1s?  If you +1 a site, will it affect your own Google results? For example, if you +1 Stack Exchange, will Stack Exchange sites be affected in your own Google results?

Answer (score 4):

There are two different types of Google Results now:

- Personalized Results
- Hide Personalized Results

From [Google's Help Page](http://support.google.com/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1710607):

> You have to be signed in to a Google Account  to get all of the
>   features of personal results. Here's how Google personalizes your
>   results when you're signed in:
>
> 1. Google products: Search for publicly and privately shared content
>      visible to you, like your Google+ (and Picasa) photos and Google+
>      posts from your friends.
> 2. Social Search: Discover relevant images and
>      pages shared by people in your Google+ circles and by suggested
>      connections.
> 3. Web History: Get customized results based on your past
>      search activity on Google, such as searches you've done or results
>      you've clicked. Learn more about Web History
> 4. Profiles in search: When
>      you search for a friend's name, you might see a link to the relevant
>      Google+ profile in the list of autocomplete predictions. With personal
>      results, you’re more likely to see your friend John's profile than
>      some John you’ve never met. Learn more about profiles in search

You can turn these on and off by toggling the following buttons on the search results page (you need to be logged in to see these buttons)

[image: Google Personalized Results Toggle Buttons]

The button on the **left** is for personalized searches (turned off in this example). The button on the **right** is for non-personalized searches and your results won't be based on the items above.

So yes, +1s from your Google+ connections will skew results when you have personalized search turned on. Also, +1s from yourself affect search results on the personalized side.

You can also set your preference on the [search settings](https://www.google.com/preferences?hl=en) page. This will only make the settings applicable to the browser you're using as it's a cookie setting and not account specific.

Comment: That’s not what the OP asked. He’s asking about **your** +1s, not the ones from your connections.

Comment: I added a second sentence in the 2nd to last paragraph regarding that because I noticed that I had originally posted the answer without actually answering it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in theory they seem like they should but currently, i would say no.

Let's say you search for something, like this page by searching the title "Do your +1's affect your own Google results?". This page ranks 1st. if you +1 it (using a chrome extension as I have), the page will show up on my g+ list of +1s. Now that I have +1 this page, if i again search the same terms, I will again get this page as the first result. If I have it set to show personal results, the result will show that i +1ed it.

This is the most important part: If I then show personal results by clicking "See all results" at the top, instead of getting my +1ed result, I get results from ppl in my circles. the actual page is nowhere to be found.

My conclusion from this experiment is that, your search results will not be affected by your +1. However, you will be made aware if you come across your +1 among your normal results. There's obviously more intricacies to the search results but I won't get into that here.

**1. +1 a site will not automatically bring it to a higher ranking in your search results than if you had not +1 in the first place.**

**2. you do not see your +1s in you personal personal results (the results that are like "170 personal results" as opposed to "76,000,000 other results")**